# Limit of sequence of vectors in $\ell^2$ with coefficients approaching $0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, limits-and-convergence

Let $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \ell^2$ be a sequence in $\ell^2$ over the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ such that: $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independend and $v_m \to v$

Let $V= \operatorname{span} \{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$

Let $\{u_p\}_{p \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$ be a sequence in $V$ such that $u_p \to u$ so we have
$$
\forall p \in \mathbb{N}: u_p = 
\sum_{m=1}^\infty
\left(
a_{p,m} \cdot v_m
\right)
$$
with $a_{m,p} \in \mathbb{C}$ and for each fixed $p \in \mathbb{N}$ there are only finitely many $m$ with $a_{p,m} \neq 0$

Further, we have for each fixed $m \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}
a_{p,m}
=0
$$
My question is if it is true that:
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}
u_p
=
a \cdot v
$$
with $a \in \mathbb{C}$

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear: if $u_p$ is an element of $V$, what is the meaning of the given equality with the sum of a series, a complex number.

Comment: it's because $V$ is the span of $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ so $u_p$ is a finite linear combination. I write that way to create the matrix $a_{p,m}$

Comment: That's certainly not working, take something like $v_n=e_1/n + e_n/n^2$, $u_n=nv_n$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling in your definition of $u_n$ the coefficient $n$ doesn't approach 0

Comment: @MateyMath: It does: in your notation, I have $a_{nn}=n$ and $a_{mn}=0$ otherwise in my example, so $\lim_{p\to\infty} a_{pn}=0$, as desired.

Comment: ok @ChristianRemling thanks